# how to handle Error Parents widget flutter

Tags: flutter

How to fix that? i'm so confusing, but this error is running when debugging, but in debug console always show error this..
container.dart

> Blockquote

```
Widget announcement(context) {
  return Container(
    height: 435,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: 6,
          color: Color(0x1B090F13),
          offset: Offset(0, -2),
        )
      ],
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
        topRight: Radius.circular(16),
      ),
    ),
    child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: const Alignment(-1, 0),
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                labelColor: vars.yellow,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                labelStyle:
                    vars.fontMedium(context, 12, FontWeight.bold, Colors.white),
                indicatorColor: vars.yellow,
                indicatorWeight: 2,
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Akan Datang',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Selesai',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 12, 0, 0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 5,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const DetailProduk()));
                            },
                            child: cardProduct(
                                context: context,
                                formatLocation: 'WIB',
                                tanggal: "Senin, 2 Juli 2023 - 20:00",
                                timeCountDown: "02:28:19",
                                urlImages: 'assets/images/kursiselesai.jpg'),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 12, 0, 0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const DetailProduk()));
                            },
                            child: cardProduct(
                                context: context,
                                formatLocation: 'WIB',
                                tanggal: "Senin, 2 Juli 2023 - 20:00",
                                timeCountDown: "02:28:19",
                                urlImages: 'assets/images/kursiselesai.jpg'),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
  );
}
```

this error in debug console
[image]

this screenshot of this app
[image]

because when i try to release application, this error not display, but in debug application running...

Comment: This issue caused by `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget that used not as a children on `Column` or `Row`.  Probably in your `cardProduct` widget. Can you provide the code ?